# Как в массив объектов записать значение из консоли

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер,
не могу разобраться с небольшим скриптом.

Есть массив данных и функция :

```
var UsersData = []; 
 var UsersObj = {id: i = 0, name: '', email: ''};

function AddUser () {
    UsersData.push(i++, name, email);
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы при вызове функции `AddUser` в консоль, можно было записать данные в массив `{name: " ", email: " "}` ?

Comment: Несколько раз прочитал, ничего не понял. Зачем AddUser  вызывать в консоль. или в консоль надо записать данные? или надо записать данные в массив? где точки с запятыми, чтоб отделить мысль? что означает UsersObj  в коде? кому куда что передать? бррр...

Comment: есть массив UserData, внутри него хранятся данные, где `{id: i = 0, name: '', email: ''}` - это элемент массива и каждая такая конструкция, последующий элемент массива. Необходимо, чтобы при вызове функции AddUser в консоль, можно было записать данные в массив. Где вместо `name, email` в консоли записывались данные

Comment: о какой консоли идет речь?

Comment: @Grundy  о google developer console

Comment: в ней невозможно сделать то что ты хочешь

Comment: @Gundy я знаю, что можно сделать через консоль. AddUser(name: 'Clarck', email: 'clarck@host.com'), но я не знаю как сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передаем данные в параметр функции. В Функции объект заносим в массив.

```js
var UsersData = [];
var UsersObj = {id: i = 0, name: '0', email: '0' };
var UsersObj2 = {id: i = 1, name: '1', email: '1' };

function AddUser(UsersObj) {
    // delete UsersObj.id;
    UsersData.push(UsersObj);
}

AddUser(UsersObj);
AddUser(UsersObj2);

console.log(UsersData);
```

Comment: Массивы удобнее выводить в консоль с помощью console.dir();

Comment: Вы не поняли! Необходимо, чтобы при вызове AddUser в консоли выводилось, что то на подобии `name: " ", email: " ";` , где вместо `" "` в той же консоли вводились значения с клавиатуры. Не знаю как правильно объяснить, потому что не понимаю как сделать

Comment: @Imp3l уже ввод с клавиатуры появился? ммм..  для того чтобы объяснить, достаточно подумать, **что** хочется сделать и получить в итоге, а не **как**

Comment: @VasilyKoshelev кому удобнее? И чем  в данном случае не удобен log?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мне кажется, что console.dir более детально (либо читабельнее) выводит информацию, т.к. она представлена в виде дерева.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не появился, я вроде бы достаточно понятно объяснил. При вызове `AddUser()` выводит `undefined`

Comment: @Imp3l ну вот сейчас при вызове `AddUser` всё нормально :) задача выполнена....... советую всё же собраться с мыслями и написать всё более понятно.. сейчас это некая каша, которая понятна только вам внутри себя, не более

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вообщем. вот задание, которое мне дали и которое я пытаюсь реализовать     1) Создать js обьект UsersObj с полями id пользователя, имя пользователя, email адрес пользователя.
2) создать глобальный массив для хранения эти пользователей
3) написать функционал для манипуляции над массивом.
- AddUser(<здесь нужные аргументы для добавления>) - функция добавления пользователя в массив